# Can $y$ be made the subject in such equation?

Tags: functions, implicit-function-theorem

I came across the equation:

$${x^2} + 2xy + {3y^2} = 1$$

I tried making $\space y \space$ the subject, but the furthest I got was:

$$ 2xy + {3y^2} = 1 - {x^2} $$

$$ y(2x + 3y) = 1 - {x^2} $$

$$ y = {{ 1 - {x^2}}\over { 2x + 3y }}$$

But I can't seem to be able to get $\space y \space$ on its own.

I even tried taking $\space \log \space$ of both sides, but that failed.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: You can solve for either $x$ or $y$ by completing the square appropriately

Comment: @MPW - Oh my goodness, that never crossed my mind. Thank you :)

Comment: You can use the quadratic formula for $ay^2+by+c=0$, with $a=3$, $b=2x$ and $y=x^2-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the quadratic equation

$$y = \frac{-2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 - 4\times(3)\times(x^2-1)}}{2\times3}$$

$$y = \frac{-2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 - 12 x^2 + 12}}{6}$$

$$y = \frac{-2x \pm \sqrt{12 - 8 x^2}}{6}$$

$$y = \frac{-x \pm \sqrt{3 - 2 x^2}}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is a quadratic form which can be written as
$$
1
= u^t A u  
= (x, y)
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This a symmetric matrix and we can calculate the eigenvectors $v_1$, $v_2$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$:

```
>> A = [1,1;1,3]
A =

   1   1
   1   3

>> [B,C]=eig(A)
B =

  -0.92388   0.38268
   0.38268   0.92388

C =

Diagonal Matrix

   0.58579         0
         0   3.41421
```

We have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{diag}{diag}
(v_1 v_2)^{-1} A(v_1 v_2) 
= (v_1 v_2)^{-1} (\lambda_1 v_1, \lambda_2 v_2)
= \diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) \iff \\
A = (v_1, v_2) \diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) (v_1, v_2)^{-1}
$$
This can be interpreted such that the matrix $T = (v_1, v_2)^{-1}$ transforms the coordinates $u$ into $u' = T u$, and $A$ is diagonal in that system, so that your equation transforms into
\begin{align}
1 
&= u^t T^{-1} T A T^{-1} T u \\
&= (u')^t \diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) u' \\
&= \lambda_1 (x')^2 + \lambda_2 (y')^2 \\
&= \left( \frac{x'}{1/\sqrt{\lambda_1}}\right)^2 +
  \left( \frac{y'}{1/\sqrt{\lambda_2}}\right)^2 \\
&= \left( \frac{x'}{a}\right)^2 +
  \left( \frac{y'}{b}\right)^2 \quad (*)
\end{align}
which is an ellipse with semi axes $a = 1/\sqrt{\lambda_1}=1.31$ and $b = 1/\sqrt{\lambda_2}=0.54$.

[image: ellipses]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gdd.png))

The idea now is to use some parametrization of $(*)$ and use $T^{-1}$ to transform into the original system.

We might use 
$$
y' = \pm b \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{x'}{a}\right)^2}
$$
which gives
$$
u = T^{-1} u' \iff \\
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.92388 &  0.38268 \\
 0.38268 &  0.92388
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
\pm b \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{x'}{a}\right)^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$